# HTTP GET request working on normal session but not in 'incognito' session

Tags: javascript, session, steam

Having some trouble understanding why this issue is happening, specifically within the Steam environment.

When I go to [this](http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?appid=730&market_hash_name=XM1014%20%7C%20Grassland%20%28Field-Tested%29) URL and am logged in to Steam, the request goes through fine and I get the return that I'm expecting. However, when I try the request in an incognito session, I get an empty set of results. I've looked through [the code that Steam itself uses to send this request](http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/javascript/economy.js) (ctrl-f '// Load' and it should bring you to the relevant code). There doesn't seem to be any identifying information being passed in this request, and even in incognito mode Steam will still load up the price history charts for the item just fine. I can't understand why the request will not work in a session in which the user isn't logged in to Steam even though the page itself will still display price history using the same request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this occurs on Valve's servers, this is simply an educated guess as to what is occurring.

When you visit this URL without being logged in, the server is sending back a [`400 Bad Request`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

It appears this is due to the lack of a `steamLogin` cookie. When you visit the URL without being logged in, these cookies are set

```
timezoneOffset
Steam_Language
community_game_list_scroll_size
recentlyVisitedAppHubs
sessionid
steamCC_<IP_OF_COMPUTER>
```

After logging in, when the request is successful, the `steamLogin` cookie also exists.

It appears you need this cookie to get the information you want.

Comment: This would possibly explain the issue, however I'm not sure if it accounts for the fact that when loading up the item page (e.g. [this item's page](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/XM1014%20%7C%20Grassland%20%28Field-Tested%29/)), the market history chart is loaded up fine, which means that the query went through. I'll do some more digging on this front though, seems like a good lead.

Comment: Hey there, a followup for anyone interested (e.g. googlers who find this): Setting the cookie steamLogin did get the request back properly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment (rep too low) but FYI, the item detail page works because the data for the graph is passed inside the html file in a  bracket. You could set up a DOM environment, load the html and scrape it out without needing to login.

As the other poster mentioned, the api call you want to use requires the steamLogin cookie to work.